# Nome de autor em meta property

Tags: facebook, html-meta-tag

Opa,

Preciso adicionar o nome de um autor do artigo, igual a essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meus códigos são:

```
<meta xmlns="" property="og:url" content="http://www.meusite.com.br/noticia/19/l-wander/emprego/testando-noticia">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.meusite.com.br/noticia/19/l-wander/emprego/testando-noticia">

<!-- Google ///////////////////////////// -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="Testando noticia, porL. Wander em 09/09/2016 09:54">
<meta itemprop="description" content="asf sfsdf as">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://meusite.com.br/images/noticias/3979f3543ba1b09e54b55578cbb506fd.jpg">

<!--Facebook /////////////////////////////-->
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Testando noticia, por L. Wander em 09/09/2016 09:54">
<meta property="og:description" content="asf sfsdf as">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://meusite.com.br/images/noticias/3979f3543ba1b09e54b55578cbb506fd.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.meusite.com.br">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="meusite Brasil">
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://www.meusite.com.br/noticia/19/l-wander/emprego/testando-noticia">
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
<meta property="article:author" content="L. Wander">
<meta property="article:publisher" content="L. Wander">

<!--Twitter /////////////////////////////-->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="meusite Brasil">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Testando noticia, porL. Wander em 09/09/2016 09:54">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Testando noticia, por L. Wander em 09/09/2016 09:54">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="Testando noticia">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://meusite.com.br/images/noticias/3979f3543ba1b09e54b55578cbb506fd.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="meusite.com.br">
```

Está normal, mas, preciso que o nome da pessoa apareça ao lado no link do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi faz um tempo, lembrei de postar a solução agora:

`<meta property="article:author" content="URL do Facebook do Autor">`